# How do I parse output from result of CURL command?

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, jenkins, sed

I have a Jenkins console output that looks like this:

```
Started by remote host 10.16.17.13
Building remotely on ep9infrajen201 (ep9) in workspace d:\Jenkins\workspace\Tools\Provision
[AWS-NetProvision] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins12345.ps1'"

Request network range: 10.1.0.0/13
{
    "networks":  [
                     "10.1.0.0/24"
                 ]
}
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I get this from a curl command that I run. to check the JENKINS_JOB_URL/lastBuild/consoleText

My question is, for the sake of some other automation I am doing, how do I get just `"10.1.0.0/24"` so I can assign it to a shell variable using LINUX tools?

Thank you

Comment: If you're running powershell, why do you want a `bash` solution, or perhaps you should fix your tags to be more inline with what you're using

Comment: I am not running powershell, I am CURL-ing from a linux machine, and I get the output in a Linux machine

Comment: That command starts with `poweshell.exe` and invokes a script that ends in `ps1`, that sure sounds like it's powershell to me, no matter what's inside that script.  That said, if you're doing something a shell somewhere within the powershell script for some reason you should look at the `jq` tool to parse json data

Comment: @Eric Renouf, Yes that is powershell that is generating the json object you see there, BUT I DO NOT HAVE ACCESS TO THAT POWERSHELL SCIPT. I can only CURL into that Jenkins box and I get the output that I pasted in the question. Now, my challenge is: How do I get the 10.1.0.0/24 in a variable using linux tools?

Comment: With the json  in question `jq '.networks[]' your_json_file` will give you that string

Comment: @Eric Renouf, Again, I do not have a json file to parse with jq. The output that I pasted is a mix of strings coming from jenkins and it also has a Json Object inbetween ... How do I parse the other non json strings out?

Comment: @Eric Renouf, here is what I get: bash-3.2$ curl -k1 -d "token=token" -X POST https://un:password@infrascode.dco.comp/job/Infoblox%20Tools/job/AWS-NetProvision/lastBuild/consoleText | jq '.networks[]'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you listed [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) among the tags of your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094260/how-do-i-use-linux-tools-to-parse-between-two-characters/51094364#51094364), I'll assume you have `jq` installed. You have to clean up your output to get JSON first, then get to the part of JSON you need. `awk` does the former, `jq` the latter.

```
.... | awk '/^{$/{p=1}{if(p){print}}/^}$/{p=0}' | jq -r .networks[0]
```

The AWK script looks for `{` on its own on a line to turn on a flag `p`; prints the current line if the flag is set; and switches off the flag when it encounters `}` all by itself.

EDIT: Since this output was generated on a DOS machine, it has DOS line endings (`\r\n`). To convert those before `awk`, additionally pipe through `dos2unix`.

Comment: that awk prints nothing :/

Comment: Not by itself, it doesn't. `awk` transforms its input. Did you pipe in the output you had in it? (I just tested this on my machine with your input, and I'm getting `10.195.3.0/24`.

Comment: testing this on my mac WITH the jq filter and I get nothing

Comment: command: curl -sk1 -d "token=token" -X POST https://URL/job/AWS-NetProvision/lastBuild/consoleText | awk '/^{$/{p=1}{if(p){print}}/^}$/{p=0}' | jq -r .networks[0]

Comment: Edited my test in so you can confirm my results. No idea why it wouldn't work on your end.

Comment: I think I got it. The box you're getting your results from is a DOS box, so results are probably DOS-formatted as well (with DOS line endings `\r\n` instead of UNIX ones `\n` used by modern Macs). This doesn't sit well with `awk`. Thus, `cat tmp.txt  | dos2unix | ...` should make it work (obviously, after installing `dos2unix` utilities).

Comment: BINGO! - You're a genius!